# Tag wiki edit action wording: "This edit clearly improves the post"

Tags: bug, review, suggested-edits, tag-wiki, wording

I found a wording bug when reviewing a tag wiki excerpt edit:

[image: Review the following tag wiki excerpt edit. approve: This edit clearly improves the post. Reject: This edit fails to improve the post]

The action options given refer to "the post" where they really should refer to "the tag wiki excerpt" instead, or perhaps just "the tag wiki".

---

I'm not sure how widespread this bug is across the network, but presumably it is somewhat.
I imagine this also affects regular tag wiki edits.

If relevant, I was on [Music: Practice & Theory Meta](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Technically, they are stored as Posts ...